# Pull data from Athena and Redshift view to a s3 bucket in csv format daily automation

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation, amazon-redshift

What is the best option to pull redshift and athena view to s3 bucket automatically every day?

This bucket is to be used by a third party company who would push this data from s3 to their system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run some code somewhere that connects to the database and runs an UNLOAD command.

For example, if you are already running an Amazon EC2 instance, then use a Linux `cron` command or Windows Scheduled Task. Alternatively, create an AWS Lambda function that runs on a schedule.

See also:

- [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)
- [UNLOAD - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/unload.html)